# bind an array of data to form array in angular

Tags: angular, bind, ngfor, formarray

I have a form where i used form array.
In getstudentsArray i'm getting data of students.
I want to display this dynamic data in formarray using ngfor.
Please help me bind the getstudentsArray  array in html form array
Can you please fix my issue.
Thanks in advance.

HTML

```html
<span formArrayName="times">
<a (click)="addGroup()">Add New Textfield</a>
<span  *ngFor="let time of timesArray.controls; let i = index;">
  <span [formGroupName]="i">                         
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lists" placeholder="enter dropdown options">  
  </span>
</span>
</span>
```

```js
getstudentsArray: any = [];

getStudentDetails(){
  const obj: any = {
    ID: this.stu_id
  }
  this.service.postmethod('studentsDetails', obj).subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.respon= res;
    this.getstudentsArray = this.respon.test;
  });
}
```

```json
{
    "test": [
        {"id": 1,"class": 5,"name": "john"},
        {"id": 2,"class": 5,"name": "tim"},
        {"id": 3,"class": 5,"name": "alex"},   
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I have data in "getstudentsArray" as shown above.  i want to bind this in html formarray.
When I bind it using ngfor I'm getting only one, even if it has 3

Comment: The way you have created formarray is wrong.

Comment: can you please explain me

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-idafsv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

i made a stackblitz of how i created form array.
Then later on explain me the binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your working solution :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xeuupi

First you need to create formgroup of object and then you need to push those groups on array. I have also added validator function if you want to add.

For validators you can say :

```
this.validators = {
   'name': Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])
};
```

And you need to pass **this.validator** instead of blank object {} in createFormGroup(...) method.

Comment: Here, where can we add a new formfield after binding i should have an option to add new fields also.

Comment: I have updated code on stackblitz with random data madam. you can verify now and set as per your needs and logic.